# Select Image File and Display it in Forms (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio

I have a form, in which it has a few pictureBoxes that i intended to use as a normal button.
first button is the select file button where when the users click the button, a window will pop up allowing the users to select files to be analyzed.
the second button is a run button where when the users have selected the desired files, clicking this will run the application to analyze the image file.
third button is a stop button to stop the analyzing process.
last button is a help button that provide the help and support.

the question is that how do i display the selected files on the form in a tabular format with basic information like file name, file type, date created and date modified?

Comment: Use a ListView control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a listview control with the .View property set to Details. Add an item and subitems for each file.